# PEP guide for dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

Is there a PEP guide to follow as convention for dictionary key style?

Particularly for using upper/lower case letters and multiple words(with space or underscore).

For example, is it a correct style to have a dictionary like this:

```
client_income = {"MrJimmy_doctor California":300}
```

I know that I can use dictionary within dictionary for storing these information, but this is just a made up example. Also, I know that there is no syntax error here, but I want to know the convention.

Comment: I don't think there is a convention for dict keys, but using snake_case is sort of the python standard if there is no other convention specified.

Comment: If you want to `**` unpack your dict, then the keys have to match the argument names, of course, but apart from that, keys can have any format. Proper names, dates, UUIDs, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no conventions on how to name the **keys** in a dictionary, they can be really arbitrary and it really depends on your application or problem you're trying to solve.